# Raspbian Stretch and minicom install error

Tags: raspberry-pi, apt-get, stretch

I've a RsPi 3 with Stretch.
I want to install minicom repo but i've an error, with :

```
 sudo apt-get install minicom
```

here's the result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  lrzsz
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lrzsz minicom
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
Need to get 250 kB/332 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,090 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf minicom armhf 2.7-1.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 129.102.1.37 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/m/minicom/minicom_2.7-1.1_armhf.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 129.102.1.37 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Here's the source.list file :

```
pi@telma:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list deb
http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi 
pi@telma:~ $
```

Does anyone have a solution to install minicom ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to just use the comment but my rep is not enough.....

Have you `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` yet?
That solves my problem.

Somehow I need to `sudo apt-get update` again after dist-upgrade to install minicom. So if `sudo apt-get install minicom` tells you it can't find minicom, you may want to run `sudo apt-get update` again.